# Change "Loaded Configuration File" for a specific domain [Not the entire server]

Tags: php, nginx, configuration

I do not want to make modifications to the default php.ini the server uses. I've made a new one to use, which is located in my site's own directory on an Nginx server. The issue I have come across is not being able to change the `Loaded Configuration File` when I go to the phpinfo page to locate it. I'd like to be able to change this so that the new configuration is only used on one site and not on others.

Default location: `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini`

The new location I need to set my one site to is `/var/www/html/domain.com/usr.ini`

I have tried changing the fastcgi_params in the site-specific nginx.conf file, but it is not updating, so I am not able to use the ini settings I need for a specific site.

The goal is to **only** affect one site by specifying its own .ini file, not the server.

> *I do not use Apache in any shape or form. This is a LEMP stack server.*